# Cascading dynamic select list's dynamic action gets triggered when the list values changes ,not only when user select a value from the list

Tags: dynamic, plsql, selectlist, oracle-apex-5.1

I am developing an application on Oracle APEX 5.1.Here I have a dynamic select list whose value depends on a page item value on the same page. So I have added this page item in the: 'Cascading LOV Paret item' field of the select list and referred to this item in the pl/sql code of the select list.
And I have defined an 'onChange' dynamic action' for the select list which submits the page.

The problem is: This dynamic action is getting executed whenever the dynamic select list gets refreshed by the change of cascading LOV parent item value. But I need the dynamic action to execute only when the user select a value in the list.

Please help me to find out where I am going wrong!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After the the child LOV gets refreshed, its value should be null. Can you add a condition on the `onChange` dynamic action so it only does its thing if the child item is not null?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Thanks for your response. But I need the dynamic action to occur when the user select  'null value'(displayed as -Current-) from the select list too.  The page content needs to be changed even for a null selection in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried change the dynamic action to fire on select instead of on change?

According to the APEX documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/advnc_dynamic_actions.htm#HTMDB28003). An onChange action fires when the LOV has been modified in some way whereas a select action fires when a user selects something in the field.

Alternatively another possible solution is in the select list properties. There is a setting called "Page Action on Selection" which can be used to submit the page when a value is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response.1) For 'on select' DA,the doc says 'select' is for text field. (Select (select) - Fires when a user selects some text in a text field. Supported User Interface Types: Desktop and jQuery Mobile Smartphone.). I have tried 'on select', but nothing happens when we select a value.     2) for 'page action on srlection',  I need to execute some pl/SQL code before submit. Can you help me with where should I keep that code so that it will get executed each time before submit.

Comment: I tried the second method by creating a process to execute before submit for the plsql code. But here too I got the same problem as in my issue. The page gets submitted for refreshing of the list values.

Comment: In regards to creating code that runs before submit. You can create a dynamic action that runs the pl/sql code with the before submit. Or what I would recommend is run it in the after submit or at validation on the processing tab.

Comment: Outside of that though I'm afraid I can't think of another solution with the exception of does the page really need to submit when a user selects a value? I would just have a button that the user clicks to submit the page after they've selected an option.